# Opening hidden files with the same application

Tags: finder, filesystem, privacy

So I still have the same Macbook Pro since 2013 and she's still running super strong.  Over these past 7 years I've managed to accumulate over 30 hidden dot files and folders in my home directory.  I know some of these files are very important, but for the ones that aren't I'd really like to get rid of them.  When trying to do my research opening these files is an absolute nightmare.  Is there any kind of app available or anything that will allow me to open these no name files with the same application.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably open them all with TextEdit, by drag & drop if they don't show anything in 'Open With', though it may not tell you much when you do. You can't add the file types to an app as default, as they often don't really have a file type. Some will be plaintext, some probably XML & some may be binary.

Some may make slightly more sense in BBEDit (freeware version is sufficient) but not if they're binary data.

I doubt any will be taking up more than 4k on disk.

BTW, my home folder has about 60 hidden dot files & folders.

Comment: Yeah right click and open with works fine it's just more clicks than I'd like.  I can even double click to open with TextEdit.  I guess I'm just frustrated with these options.

Comment: Just drag select the whole lot & drop them on TextEdit

Comment: Yeah I can even do that with my text editor of choice and that works as well.

Comment: If there is 'more clicks than I'd like' situation then one can always use ranger (or nnn) as file manager and vim as default text editor. No clicks whatsoever :-).